# How do I efficiently find the root in a map which represents a tree in Scala

Tags: scala, tree, root

How do I find the root in a Map which represents a spanning tree in Scala.

Below is an example of a Map which contains a tree.

```
val l = List((1,List(2,3,4)), (2,List(5,6)), (3,List(7,8,9)))
val m1 = l.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2))}
```

Comment: Question updated. It should conform to StackOverflow standards now.

Comment: The code creates the data structure. The code does not find the roots of the tree. Please remove the minus points. The question is how to find the roots of the tree (efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that returns a list of all the nodes that do not appear in any of the lists of leaves.

```
l.collect{ case (k, _) if !l.exists(_._2.contains(k)) => k }
```

A more efficient two-line version:

```
val leaves = l.flatMap(_._2).toSet
l.collect{ case (k, _) if !leaves.contains(k) => k }
```

Even more efficient:

```
val leaves: Set[Int] = l.flatMap(_._2)(collection.breakOut)
l.collect{ case (k, _) if !leaves.contains(k) => k }
```

All of these return `List(1)` for the sample data.